# js scrollbar width

Tags: javascript, width, scrollbar, conditional-statements

I found this script online http://javascript.jstruebig.de/javascript/70. I'm just wondering what this line means:

```
if(!width) width = document.body.offsetWidth-document.body.clientWidth;
```

What does the !width condition mean? If it is not initialized? Also, are there any shorter scripts that provide the same functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: If the width variable is false.

Comment: but how can the variable be false if it has always been given int values?

Comment: What's the width of a scrollbar when there is no scrollbar?

Comment: That's actually if the width variable is `falsey` which is any value that `==` would evaluate as false like `0`, an empty string, `null`, `undefined`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!width just checks the falsey value of a variable, the more explicit check would be

```
if(typeof width === "undefined") {
   width = document.body.offsetWidth-document.body.clientWidth;
}
```

- offsetWidth is the full width of the element including border and scrollbar
  client
- clientWidth is the width of the element which includes the padding but excludes the border and scrollbar

In short, that logic just gets the width of the border and scrollbar of the page. There may be different implementations, but there is not a shorter logic than a subtraction of two operands.